# Plotting in two different scenes

Tags: python, vtk, mayavi

I am trying to plot two image plane widgets in two different scenes in mayavi at once. But both planes are shown in the first scene. Has anybody an idea how to fix this?

Here is an example of my code:

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab
from mayavi.mlab import axes, outline
from traitsui.api import View, Item, Group, HGroup
from mayavi.core.pipeline_base import PipelineBase
from mayavi.core.ui.api import MayaviScene, SceneEditor, MlabSceneModel

class myclass():
  p='somedata[20][20][20]' #I can't give you the data here because it's too big
  scene = Instance(MlabSceneModel, ())        
  sx = Instance(MlabSceneModel, ())
  plot = Instance(PipelineBase)

  def function(self):
    self.src = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(self.p)
    self.plot2 = self.scene.mlab.pipeline.image_plane_widget(self.src,         
                            plane_orientation='x_axes',             
                            slice_index=0,
                            #vmin=0, vmax=140,
                            colormap='hot')

    self.sx.scene.parallel_projection = True
    side_src = self.plot.ipw._get_reslice_output() #gets the data for the 2d planes
    self.ipw = self.sx.mlab.pipeline.image_plane_widget(     #creates the 2d views
                            side_src,
                            plane_orientation='z_axes',
                            #vmin=self.data.min(),
                            #vmax=self.data.max(),
                            #figure=self.sx.mayavi_scene,
                            name='Cut view X',
                            colormap='hot',
                            )

    mlab.colorbar(title='Wert', orientation='vertical', nb_labels=5, label_fmt='%.3f')            #adds a colorbar at the left side of the screen
    mlab.view(azimuth=50,elevation=50,distance=80,focalpoint=(10,15,10))      #defines the starting view of the camera
    mlab.roll(110)
    self.scene.scene_editor.background = (0, 0, 0)
    view = View(HGroup(Item('scene', editor=SceneEditor(scene_class=MayaviScene),
                                  height=400, width=500, show_label=False),
                       Item('sx',editor=SceneEditor(scene_class=MayaviScene),
                                  height=400, width=500, show_label=False),),
                resizable=True,
                )

myclass()
```

I couldn't find a solution on the web, there are examples with multiple scenes but I can't figure out why it works there and not in my code. Any help would be nice.

When I try using the `figure` kwarg in the `image_plane_widget`, like this

```
self.plot = mlab.pipeline.image_plane_widget(self.src,         
                            plane_orientation='x_axes',             
                            slice_index=0,
                            #vmin=0, vmax=140,
                            figure=self.sx,
                            colormap='hot')
```

it returns following error:

> TraitError: The 'figure' trait of an ImagePlaneWidgetFactory instance
>   must be a Scene or None, but a value of
>     was specified.

Answer (score 0):

To specify the scene directed in your pipeline calls include the `figure` kwarg and similar, e.g. `mlab.pipeline.image_plane_widget(*args, figure=self.scene)`. Otherwise if `figure` is not specified, the pipeline calls go to `mlab.gcf()` which is typically the last created figure.

Comment: As you maybe did see, I have the figure kwarg in my code but I marked it as comment because its not working with figure either.

Comment: That is because `self.sx` is not initialized. In fact your code snippet has no object model at all (i.e. `self` is never defined). I didn't look at your code carefully but I assumed you realized that.

Comment: oh yeah the code normaly is written in a function with a declaration of self

Comment: Yes follow the class structure of tutorials such as http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_mayavi_traits_ui.html